# A particular SQL statement

Tags: sql

I have this kind of table_unit and i want to select all the rows of source_f having the similar values between them but not showing all the rows of target_f with the values similar between them

Look this image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89718989/stackoverflow.jpg

I want to select all the rows of source_f having similar values, like "Failed ot obtain a list of players" of Globalerrorcode101 and the second Globalerrorcode200 but refusing all the rows that in target_f have the similar values... so basically the selection i want, it must print only the IDs 2,3 and 4, but not 1 and 5...

Comment: None of this looks like a sql table or row data. Can you reword your question to include some table schema, example data, and an example of what you are looking to get out of this query?

Comment: Why should your result contain ID 3 but not 1? Are you expecting your query to translate the text from some other language to english and then compare?

Comment: As i asked i'm trying to compare all the rows having the same string content but withouth the rows of other coulm having the same content... basically there are 2 languages... source_f is the original language translated in english and target_f is my local translation... now i want to compare all the results of target_f having the same string inside except the translations already done having also the same string content

Answer (score 0):

What sql engine are you using?

At a theoretical level you are looking for reverse result of an intersect http://www.essentialsql.com/learn-to-use-union-intersect-and-except-clauses/.

This will be a complicated query. You may have to do 
 1. sql for left outer join,
 2. sql for a right outer join 
 3. and do union of the two result sets.

HTH..